# Trying to find text in an article that may contain quotation marks

Tags: python, html

I'm using python's findall function with a reg expression that should work but can't get the function to output results with quotation marks in them ('"). 
This is what I tried:

`Description = findall('<p>([A-Za-z ,\.\—'":;0-9]+).</p>\n', text)`

The quotation marks inside the reg expression are creating the hassle and I have no idea how to get around it.

Comment: Use a html parser instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Try adding a blackslash to the single quote inside the regex. '<p>([A-Za-z ,\.\-\'":;0-9]+).</p>\n'

Comment: Thanks Sachith Rukshan, that makes it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing the backslash before the single quote like Sachith Rukshan suggested makes it work